# Does a solution to $Am=0$ imply a solution to $A^Tb=0$?

Tags: matrices

If if $m$ is non-zero and $Am=0$ has a solution, with $A$ some $n \times n$ matrix, can we be certain $A^{T}b=0$, for some non-zero $b$?

I feel like the answer is yes (or at least I can't think of a counterexample), but I have no idea how to verify this. I can't even conceive a starting point, though I've been playing around with the equation for $n=2$ for the matrix, to no success.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true: Existence of a nonzero solution $b$ to $Ab = 0$ is equivalent to $\det A  = 0$, and $\det A = \det (A^T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A deeper fact is that the rank of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A^T$. So for square matrices, the dimensions of their nullspaces are the same.